# Most useful shortcut in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-cdt

I would like to make a cheat sheet presenting the most useful (and time saving) shortcut for Eclipse CDT (C++).

Can you share what are the most useful shortcuts that you use in CDT?

Please, post only general shortcuts (available when doing C++) or CDT specific.

Answer (score 61):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> : Switch between source and header files.

Answer (score 54):

Summary of all the shortcuts in this thread and some more.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> - Switch between source and header files.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> - Open Element

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - Open File/Resource.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> - Explore Macro Expansion.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> - Show proposals to complete you've written.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> - Opens the call hierarchy for a function

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - Adds an #include for the header file in which the current element is declared

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> - Corrects indentation of the selected text - very useful in my opinion

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> - Deletes current row

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> - Opens a search dialog; the "C/C++ Search" tab searches through indexed locations

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> - Opens a member browser of the current class, enabling to fastly open a method

<kbd>F3</kbd> - Open declaration

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> - When a function, object or var is selected : find all occurences of it in the project.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> - Textual search of the currently selected text.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click - Go to the definition of the item.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> - Incremental search in the current file

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> - To search forward for a highlighted text in a file.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> - To search backward for a highlighted text in a file

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> - Go to previous / go to next edited or viewed place.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> - Maximize or un-maximize current Editor Window (also works for other Windows

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Up/Down Arrow - Jump to previous / jump to next method

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> - Jump to last location edited

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> - With a bracket selected: jump to the matching closing or opening bracket

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> - Comment/uncomment all selected lines with //

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> - Comment selected block with /* ... */

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> - Uncomment /* ... */ selected block

Comment: what about 'compile a script' and 'build a script' and 'run' ?

Comment: @tqjustc I think it is `CTRL` + `B`

Answer (score 43):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> : Open Element.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> : Open File/Resource.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> : Explore Macro Expansion.

Answer (score 23):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> : Show proposals to complete you've written.

Answer (score 22):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>: Shows a list of actions with their corresponding shortcuts. ;)

Answer (score 18):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>: Opens the call hierarchy for a function

Answer (score 15):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> , <kbd>N</kbd> : Rename a function or variable throughout a project.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a list of the ones I use most often (excluding the ones from previous responses):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - adds an include statement; the included header file is the one in which the current element is declared in
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> - corrects indentation of the selected text - very useful in my opinion
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> - deletes current row
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> - moves the selected text (or current line if no text is selected) up or down
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> - move to the previous/next location you edited; for example, if you browse through a few function declarations, and then want to go back to where you started from, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to move to the previous locations
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> - opens a search dialog; the "C/C++ Search" tab searches through indexed locations and is fast, but the "File Search" tab searches through all the text in your projects, and can come in handy when you're searching for a "hidden" element (for example, when searching for a macro defined under an #ifdef _WINDOWS, but _WINDOWS is not currently defined in your project)

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>: Build all projects

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>: Run

<kbd>F11</kbd>: Debug

> Note: The above shortcuts are applicable to all eclipse version

---

> Manual Shortcuts from ***Preference > General > Keys***
>
> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>: Build Project (current active project)

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> : Opens a member browser of the current class, enabling to fastly open a method.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>: Go to the next source-file opened as a tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>: Go to the previous file

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the default bindings to get these - but I like:

<kbd>F3</kbd> : Open declaration.

<kbd>F4</kbd> : Find text in project.

<kbd>F4</kbd> is self-explanatory, but <kbd>F3</kbd> has some intricacies: if you use it on a function call it will take you to the definition, and if you use it on a definition it will take you to the declaration.

Comment: Ctrl+Click on a declaration does the same as F3

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> : When a function, object or var is selected : find all occurences of it in the project (works also with java).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> : Textual search of the currently selected text.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click : Go to the definition of the item.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> : Incremental search in the current file

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>(numerical keypad) : outline - folds all functions - for a quick view

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> : this auto indents code

Comment: I think, Ctrl+a followed by Ctrl+i is the better choice if you jut want auto indetation since Ctrl+Shift+f auto formats the whole code, not only the indentation.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> opens a parallel editor for same source file.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> : To search forward for a highlighted text in a file.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>: To search backward for a highlighted text in a file

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> : Selected method: Switch between inline, out of class in .h and out of class in .cpp

Answer (score 1):

For me, this's one of the most useful key shortcuts, *especially when in **debug mode***:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> - Go to previous / next cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I'm getting to Eclipse for J2EE in creating classes is to (re)map (**Preferences->General->Keys**) *"New (Class)"* to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, and selecting the non-existing class text before so it populates the new class dialog with the class name.

Unfortunately, you still have to enter source file and header file names in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>: Select a block.

Answer (score 0):

`Shift`+ `Alt`+ `G` : Generate getters and setters (bind it)

`Alt` + `Ctrl` + `↑` : Duplicate the line(s)

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `/` :Fold all

`Ctrl` + `*` :Unfold all

`Ctrl` + `/` :Enable/disable folding

Answer (score 0):

Debugging:

<kbd>F11</kbd> Start debugging

<kbd>F5</kbd> Step into a function

<kbd>F6</kbd> Step over a function

<kbd>F7</kbd> Step out of a function

<kbd>F8</kbd> Continue to next breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + shift + ^/v    ----- move through the function

ctrl + w              ----- close a open window