# F2 function key and same key in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, file, ide, prototype, qt-creator

When you press `F2` on any word such `strtok` in `qtcreator IDE` it open location of definition of `strtok`, Now i need to this hotkey in `eclipse IDE`, What's `F2` in `eclipse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one:

<kbd>F3</kbd> : Open declaration.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1317528/26449) answer.

Comment: Please check that F3 is bound to 'Open declaration' by typing 'Open declaration' into the filter field at Window / Preferences / General / Keys.