# Most useful (productive) shortcuts in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

What is the your most useful and productive keyboard shortcut in Qt Creator?

Following the trend of great questions asked about [Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266862/most-useful-shortcut-in-eclipse-cdt), [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim), [Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: Ctrl-K is a game changer; it allows locating any file, performing any commands, going to the help of every class in very few keystrokes

Comment: Well I think it's a good question! Don't know why closed.

Comment: Great question and thanks for bump up nice discussion about that here. There are always people who want close discussion for some "formal" reason if the format is not suitable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Comment/uncomment lines (select text and press). With this shortcut you can simply comment very large piece of code and uncomment it in future:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Autocomplete:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

History of clipboard. You get popup menu with all text which you pasted in Qt Creator and if you choose something and press Enter you paste this formatted text into your code

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: How do you auto-format a piece of code?

Comment: @nbro useful shortcut too, but I thought that it famous shortcut :) It is Ctrl+I

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>F2</kbd> aka `"Follow Symbol Under Cursor"`

(You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> for this.)

Let me explain. In visual studio to obtain the same you have `F12 (Go to definition)` but this one open the search result and need you to select the possible matches. The difference between instant result and  a possible two seconds or more to get what you want (especially with common names like `open`)

<kbd>F4</kbd>  aka `"Switch\Header Source"`

In several other visual text editors for C++ (including Visual) you have to manually locate the header corresponding to the current source or vice-versa. But it's effectiveness greatly depend on whether or not you are using [SCU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit) for your classes.

Comment: `Alt` + `Left`/`Right`, to switch back and forth between two source files. Especially useful in combination with `Ctrl`+`Click`.

Comment: I would like to add that using `Ctrl + Tab` functions like Alt+Tab does, allowing you to switch between all files opened in the editor. Very useful for toggling between two files which aren't header+source (F4).

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + U` - Find usage of symbol in project under cursor

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + I` -- Open Include Hierarchy
https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Creator_Keyboard_Shortcuts - List of some popular shortcuts