# How to change the default search mode to "File Search" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, search, eclipse-cdt

When using Eclipse on a large, collaborative project, I use the Search utility to find occurrences of objects and strings across the files in the Workspace. Whenever clicking on the search button in the toolbar, the dialog defaults to the *C/C++ Search* tab. However, 99.9% of the time, I need the *File Search* tab.

[This page](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/eclipse-default-to-file-search-tab-in.html) hints on how to set the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the *File Search* tab, but I am habitually using the mouse to open that dialog.

Is there a way to configure the *Search* button to open in the *File Search* tab?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the check box *Remember last used page*, found under the button *Customize...*

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately CodeWarrior 10.6 (based on Eclipse Juno) doesn't have this checkbox.  But the almost-as-good work-around is to uncheck all the checkboxes except "File Search".  To do other project searches use Ctrl-Alt-H, Ctrl-Shift-G, Ctrl-Alt-G etc.
A full shortcut list is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266862/most-useful-shortcut-in-eclipse-cdt/11185069